# CKEditor 4 How to Add Table Without User Interaction (i.e. without dialog)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

I have already all required properties of table (i.e. rows, cols counts, style, class, header style, etc.).

I need to add table with this properties when user clicks on my custom button, without going through any dialog.

I thought about showing dialog and substituting required fields with my data and triggering OK click. But this.. kinda ugly solution.

Please tell me, is there any elegant solution for this task ?

Comment: The most straightforward solution would be to generate the HTML of the table and insert it with [editor.insertHtml](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-method-insertHtml). Is there anything wrong with it?

Comment: When I do so, CKEditor ruins class I given it.

Comment: Try adding your CSS first with `editor.document.appendStyleText` or `editor.document.appendStyleSheet` (once upon `instanceReady` event).

Comment: I'm not using styles, but I need class. Ckeditor gives its own class automatically and replaces mine.

Comment: My point is, your class (e.g. `myTableClass`) should be defined in some stylesheet which is *already* present in the same document, to make CKEditor being aware of it. E.g. `<style>.myTableClass { color: green }</style>`. Is that the case?

Comment: It is already defined, in content.css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved problem by actually hack on default values to make them getter-function like, and clicking ok button once dialog is shown:

(warning, coffee)

```
CKEDITOR.on 'dialogDefinition', (ev) ->
  if ev.data.name is 'table'
    info = ev.data.definition.getContents 'info'
    advanced = ev.data.definition.getContents 'advanced'

    # HACK: default value now returns always value I have control on
    info.get('txtRows')['default'] = { toString: -> self.ckeditor_table_rows }
    info.get('txtCols')['default'] = { toString: -> self.ckeditor_table_cols }

    # setup some normal defaults
    info.get('txtWidth')['default'] = ''
    info.get('txtBorder')['default'] = '0'
    info.get('selHeaders')['default'] = 'row'
    advanced.get('advCSSClasses')['default'] = 'table table-striped'

    ev.data.definition.dialog.on 'show', ->
      # make it create table, once dialog shown
      this.getButton('ok').click()
      # hide my own popover-like dialog
      $('.has-popover').popover('hide')
```

Trick here is `toString` method will be called each time default value will try to convert to string. And exactly this happens when this default value being put down to inputs.