# Creating tables within ckeditor from uploaded files

Tags: excel, ms-word, ckeditor

Would it be possible to create and populate tables within ckeditor from uploaded files?

A user would choose a file from their machine in any format such as word, excel etc and it could display a formatted table in the editor....

Answer (score 1):

It is pretty clear that [one can create a table in CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/addon/table). Also, [it is possible to add a table automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19761733/ckeditor-4-how-to-add-table-without-user-interaction-i-e-without-dialog). Now, if you want to automatically add a table based upon the content of an uploaded file, then:

- create a form where the file can be uploaded
- implement the feature with which one can upload the file
- make sure you know where your files are, either using a database or a deterministic algorithm
- implement a server-side functionality which prepares the content (table) data
- use the prepared data as input at client-side